Permission denied launching ROS2 and Gazebo
I have installed the ROS2 humble framework and also loaded the corresponding Gazebo simulation environment. I do all this on Dev vonatiner in Visual Studio Code. And I want to run some Gazebo startup simulation at the beginning
I have tried to execute the command ign gazebo -v 4 -r visualize_lidar.sdf from https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Gazebo/Gazebo.html
But I got the following error:
libEGL warning: failed to open /dev/dri/renderD128: Permission denied

libEGL warning: failed to open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied

Where could I have gone wrong?
